# Fetch API data using React

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a react, which uses django rest framework API. I'm to get JSON data but it seems I'm not fetching the information correctly or I'm not rendering in the right way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' ;
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: []
  };
async componentDidMount() {

fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos/')
.then(results =>{
  console.log(results)
  const get_todos = results.map( c=>{
    return {
      id: c.id,
      title: c.title,
      descripttion: c.title
    };
  });

  const newstate = Object.assign({},this.state,{
      todos: get_todos
    });
    this.setState(newstate);
  }).catch(error=> console.log(error));
}
render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
       {this.state.todos} 
    </div>
  )
 }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
state = { loading : true }
componentDidMount() {
 fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos/')
  .then(blob => blob.json())
  .then(response => {
    ...
  })
}
```